# Can I store items in my apartment?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

After finishing a couple of quests, you are directed to go to your apartment. If I have items in my inventory that I want to keep but don't want to carry around with me everywhere, is it safe to stash these items somewhere in my apartment?

In Fallout 3, shortly into the main quest there you also gain access to your own house, where the game indicates that it is safe for you to keep items there. Does your apartment in Deus Ex: Human Revolution work the same way?

Comment: I don't have a real answer for this - I don't know if items remain where you left them when you change areas. What I do know is that I haven't been back yet after leaving Detroit. I wouldn't rely much on the idea.

Comment: @Ian My latest save is in my apartment, with some additional weapons on the ground. Guess I can just see if they're still there when I get back after my next mission.

Comment: I'm only part-way through the story, but I was also tempted and decided not to risk is. The DX3 development team seems faithful to DX1 in so many ways that (1) I'm sure I won't be able to get to my apartment at will, and (2) even when I can, I wouldn't be surprised if some or all of the contents change in some way.

Comment: Spoiler alert - you do get back into your apartment, lol.

Comment: I checked my apartment after doing some more quests and advancing the main plot (but haven't left Detroit yet), and my items are still there. I stopped playing just as I left Detroit for another area for the main quest, so I'll check again once I get back to the hub.

Comment: I think the lack of an item check-in is the only real flaw to the design of the game.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can. I dropped a few things in the apartment the first time I dropped by. A few locations later and a trip back to Detroit and those items are still there.

Be mindful that you don't always have access to the apartment though.

Comment: I can confirm this. After the first main quest mission away from Detroit, I returned to my apartment and my items were exactly as I left them.

Answer (score 6):

I'm still in act 1, but I've left a lot of stuff in my apartment. It all seems to be fine, so I may change my answer later.

Personally, I would have loved a storage locker or something. ;)

**Update**: I'm back in Detroit and all the stuff I left in my apartment is still there. That said though, there have been some interesting resets outside of the place. Broken walls fixed and moveable objects returned to their initial positions.

Answer (score 4):

Also works with other locations.

I killed the punks behind the gas station gunshop, and dropped my tranq for a shotgun. I got tired of it, sold it, and came back. Tranq was still there.

Answer (score 2):

Actually (at least in the PC version) you can safely stash items in:

- Detroit (streets) - available from the very beginning; it's best to stash items somewhere near one of the weapon dealers, so that you can easily manage surplus stuff; a good choice would be the "Hobo corner" near gas station, not far from Sarif HQ. Also, *slight story spoiler*,

> don't place the items in Sarif HQ nor DPD - that areas will get off-limits for/at some time.

- Hengsha (streets) - IMO the best bet is the Hengsha Whore Hotel, available from the very start of first visit in Hengsha; I think that only storing some spares makes sense here, as Detroit is visited more times and covers more of the gameplay. Also, *slight story spoiler*,

> don't place the items in Alice Garden Pods - that area will get off-limits for/at some time.

To sum up: your apartment is not a very good place, as it's hard to use it as an effective stash - you won't be visiting it too often compared to streets. Simply use the streets; no NPC will bother with your items at all, and they will stay there until the riots start.

After that, you're up to your arm augs to help you manage your stuff, as you *won't* be getting back to Detroit after that, and your following visit in Hengsha will also be the last.

Note that some subareas *do* get reset with time (doors re-closed, barrel/boxes/computer terminals reset etc), but the loot *doesn't*.

Source: my recent gameplay;

> all the items left in various places during the very first visit were still there during the riots.