# Where is it safe to store items in each hub?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

My storage is full and there's so many nice things to pick up. Is there a safe place I can drop things off at where they will be accessable later on? What I'm looking for is something like Diablo 2's "stash"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I store items in my apartment?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28671/can-i-store-items-in-my-apartment)

Comment: By my knowledge (finished DE:HR 3 times) there's no storage, so I think he's actually talking about Deus Ex, not Human Revolution and it's just been mistagged.

Comment: @Mr Smooth that's possible, either way there's no diablo 2 style stash in either game.

Comment: I'm talking about DX:HR. But I'm looking for storage in each city, or a single stash that's accessable anywhere. Not just in Detroit as discussed in @yx_ 's link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no shared stash that's accessible from every city.  However, if you drop items in places such as in your apartment, or in one of the hotel rooms in the Hung Hua hotel, such as the room with Mei, they will remain there should you revisit that area in a later part of the game.

Most of the time, I've found that its worth it just to sell whatever you don't need and keep it as spare cash to buy stuff later.  There's plenty of goodies to be found everywhere if you explore enough and you can find most weapons multiple times.

Comment: Not entirely true... NEVER SELL 10mm PISTOL AMMO!! That got me wondering what else is scarce in supply. Weapon upgrades, probably.